# c# VisualStudio error System.NullReferenceException when use string equals

Tags: c#

C# WindowsForms App in Visual Studio 2015 community.
I create combobox item with 2 values
When i create button and whant add compare condition.

```
client its string = text selected in combobox
If client = text1 value - launch app1
If client = text2 value - launch app2
```

But when i use equal function i get error.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
public partial class Form1 : Form
string client;

public Form1()

InitializeComponent();  

public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

comboBox1.DisplayMember.ToString();
string client = comboBox1.Text;

public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

if (client.Equals("notepad")) 
Process.Start("notepad.exe");
```

But when i launch app i get `System.NullReferenceException` error.

Comment: Please note that posting random snippets from code doesn't really help - in future, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `if ( !IsNullOrEmpty(client) && client.Equals("notepad"))` might help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
but i isnt understend what is !IsNullOrEmpty mean?

Comment: you get `System.NullReferenceException` when your `client` variable is a  `null` value.